# Word document how to find date when the text was Last modified?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document (.docx) received by email. Can I tell when the text was last modified. This is not the same as the file system's last modified date of the physical  file where the document is stored on my disk, since the latter is the date when I saved the file to the disk from my mail program . Is the modification date saved in the document itself as a document  property in a way that would be  preserved in email or Skype  transmission ? Unfortunately Word ->File -> Properties is of no use: it simply shows the file system's date for the physical  file, i.e the transmission date. I would expect Word to save the date in the document itself, as it does "total editing time" or "Author" (not the same as the file system's owner property). Thank you!

Comment: What version are you using? What do you see when you go to File -> Info -> Related Dates -> Last modified.

Comment: I don't have Word, but I've just extracted a docx file (it's actually a zip file containing some xml files) and after searching for strings that look like dates (`grep -P -r -o '.{0,50}[^/-]20\d\d-\d\d.{0,20}' .` on linux) found the `<dcterms:created>` and `<dcterms:modified>` elements in the file `docProps/core.xml`. Maybe this data is what's accessible using @ReddyLutonadio 's instructions.

Comment: @NiccoloM. That is the case. If you delete that element in the .xml file word shows blank in the Last modified field mentioned by ReddyLutonadio. But the OP should understand that that makes the last modified date very easy for a knowledgeable user to modify!